# Not able to understand declaration in c++

Tags: c++

I am not able to understand what this declaration does in C++?
What does the `0` in parantheses do?

```
unsigned long num (0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializes the variable `num` with `0`.

It's also a *definition*, not only *declaration* in this case..

Comment: To be fair, it's both, as is usually the case with variables.

Answer (score 3):

It initializes the variable to zero.

Answer (score 3):

There are several types of variable initialization in C++:

1. C-like initialization     **type identifier = initial_value;** —
   example: `int x = 0;`
2. Constructor initialization **type identifier (initial_value);** — example `int x (0);`
3. Uniform initialization **type identifier {initial_value};**  — example `int x {0};`

Your example is for the second initialization type.

Comment: Is it worth noting that uniform initialization is a feature of C++11?